# AWS Cloud Development Kit (CDK) No Container Instances were found in your cluster

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I want to deploy fastapi application as a service using AWS Elastic Container Service of type EC2. While deploying application, it is raising error ***No Container Instances were found in your cluster***. Here is code for Cloud Development Kit using Python.

```
from pathlib import Path

from aws_cdk import (
    aws_autoscaling as autoscaling,
    aws_ec2 as ec2,
    aws_ecs as ecs,
    App,
    Stack,
)

app = App()
stack = Stack(
    app,
    "sample-aws-ec2-integ-ecs",
    env={"region": "ap-south-1", "account": "xxxxxxxxx"},
)

# Create a VPC with public subnets
vpc = ec2.Vpc.from_lookup(stack, "dev-vpc", vpc_id="vpc-xxxxxxxx")

# Create a cluster with the VPC and enable CloudWatch Container Insights
cluster = ecs.Cluster(stack, "EcsCluster", vpc=vpc, container_insights=True)

web_server_sg = ec2.SecurityGroup.from_security_group_id(
    stack, "Dev-Pub-SG", security_group_id="sg-xxxxxxxx"
)

# ! creating auto scaling group
auto_scaling_group = autoscaling.AutoScalingGroup(
    stack,
    "asg",
    vpc=vpc,
    instance_type=ec2.InstanceType("t2.micro"),
    machine_image=ecs.EcsOptimizedImage.amazon_linux2(),
    security_group=web_server_sg,
    associate_public_ip_address=True,
    vpc_subnets=ec2.SubnetSelection(subnet_type=ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC),
    key_name="asg-key",
    desired_capacity=1,
)
capacity_provider = ecs.AsgCapacityProvider(
    stack, "capacity_provider", auto_scaling_group=auto_scaling_group
)
cluster.add_asg_capacity_provider(provider=capacity_provider)

# Create a task definition with a container listening on port 80
task_definition = ecs.Ec2TaskDefinition(stack, "TaskDef")

container = task_definition.add_container(
    "web", image=ecs.AssetImage(str(Path(".").resolve().parent)), memory_limit_mib=512
)

port_mapping = ecs.PortMapping(
    container_port=8000, host_port=8000, protocol=ecs.Protocol.TCP
)

container.add_port_mappings(port_mapping)

# Create a service with the task definition and a desired count of 1
service = ecs.Ec2Service(
    stack, "Service", cluster=cluster, task_definition=task_definition, desired_count=1
)
app.synth()
```

I had tried the sample examples provided in [aws-examples](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cdk-examples/blob/master/python/ecs/ecs-service-with-advanced-alb-config/app.py) as well. It has the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

Try setting `capacity_provider_strategies` for the service:

```
service = ecs.Ec2Service(
    stack,
    "Service",
    cluster=cluster,
    task_definition=task_definition,
    desired_count=1,
    capacity_provider_strategies=[
        ecs.CapacityProviderStrategy(
            capacity_provider=capacity_provider.capacity_provider_name, weight=1
        )
    ],
)
```